# Displaying barcodes for completed order status email notification ONLY

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, barcode, email-notifications

On my WooCommerce web site I use [Woocommerce Order Barcodes](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-order-barcodes-2/?_ga=1.23255610.1433026117.1480954042) to display a order barcodes on email notifications. 
I would like to hide or remove this barcode and display it **ONLY** on **completed** order status email notifications.

I have tried to edit the plugin file (I know this is not recommended). I have removed this (line 128 - 129) in **`class-woocommerce-order-barcodes.php`** plugin file:

```
// Add barcode to order complete email
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', array( $this, 'get_email_barcode' ), 1, 1 );
```

But it removes the barcodes from all email notifications.

How can I remove these barcodes from email notification and show it only on completed email notification?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The turn around to make it work only for completed order status email notifications, is to add just this small condition in an IF statement:

```
$order->has_status( 'completed' )
```

So you could try it this way first:

```
if (!$this->has_status( 'completed' ) ){
    add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', array( $this, 'get_email_barcode' ), 1, 1 );
}
```

---

But as I am not sure to get the $order object ($this) in there, I have looked further in the code of this plugin.

> At **line 358** you have the code below where I have add the condition.

```
/**
 * Get barcode for display in an email
 * @access  public
 * @since   1.0.0
 * @param   object $order Order object
 * @return  void
 */
public function get_email_barcode ( $order ) {

    if( ! $order ) return;

    // HERE is my condition  <====  <====  <====  <====  <====  <====  <====
    if (!$order->has_status( 'completed' ) ) return;

    // Generate correctly formatted HTML for email
    ob_start(); ?>

// … / …
// code of the function continues …
```

Here I am pretty sure that is going to work, as I we get already the **`$order`** object. The only thing is that you will have to add this code again each time you will update that plugin.

> As this is untested, I am not sure that it will work. Please give me a feed back on it

Comment: As usual your tweak works like a charm, thank you Loïc you're the #ONE